# How to pass multiple incompatible character sets to mySQL?

Tags: sql, character-encoding

Consider the following scenario: There is a SQL table which holds data in multiple character sets that are incompatible with eachother. An example would be a table with a column in latin-1, one in KOR, and one in JIS.

While this example may not fit this additional requirement, suppose for a moment that no character set exists which includes all symbols used in all three columns. How do you, for example, enter new data here efficiently?

A connection to a SQL database holds its own character set, which can be modified using a statement, but obviously, no simple command in a single character set would suffice for entering a single row of data in one statement.

*I realize that the use of many legacy character sets, especially for web applications, is not a recommended thing to do. However, the question remains very relevant for older or inherited software.*

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot store all the data as UTF-8 and translate different columns from/to different encodings on input/output?

Comment: @rd_nielsen In most cases, UTF-8 will cover you. There may be edge cases where it may not (CJK ideographs / Han unification problems come to mind).

Answer (score 0):

**Use introducers**

By using special 'introducer' variables it is possible to combine multiple character sets within the same statement. As an example, send to the SQL database:

```
INSERT INTO  `table` (`row1`, `row2`) VALUES (_sjis'<S1>', _cp1250'<S2>');
```

In this example, the query is telling the SQL server that the data in  is encoded using Shift-JIS, and the data in  is encoded using cp1250. The query is written in whatever the character set of the connection happens to be.

If the character set(s) in the query do not match those of the column(s), then the SQL server will attempt a conversion for each pair of mismatched character sets. If a conversion fails, then the query will fail with the error (replace `<data>`,  `<column>`, and `<row>` with values)

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '<data>' for column '<column>' at row <row>
```

Now suppose that the connection is using a simple ASCII character set. That means that if there happened to be a 0x27 byte `'` sign in the shift-JIS string (which can entirely not be an actual quotation mark in the string in question because it's a non-ASCII compatible multibyte encoding), then the statement could lead to a SQL injection problem.

Thus, there is a need to 'escape' the strings in question. When we're dealing with a bunch of different character sets, namely:

1. The character set of the program code.
2. The character sets of the database columns
3. The character set of the connection.
4. The character set of the 'SQL client'.
5. The character set of the SQL host system, or the 'default'.

This can quickly turn into quite the headache so most modern programming languages have special SQL connector libraries that take care of the issue for you. Unfortunately SQL does not support introducers inside of parametrized queries, which means, in this case, that we cannot use these handy tools and have to fall back to more ancient methods. What needs to be done is to escape the strings manually in the character set of the connection. An example in PHP:

```
// Assume $PDO is a PDO object, $shiftjis_string is our JIS string, 
// and $cp1250_string is a string in CP1250. 
$v1 = $PDO->quote($shiftjis_string);
$v2 = $PDO->quote($cp1250_string);
$query = "INSERT INTO  `table` (`row1`, `row2`) VALUES _sjis'{$v1}', _cp1250'{$v2}'; "; 
$result = $PDO->query($query);
```

As long as we take care not to change the character set of the underlying connection between the calls to `quote()` and `query()` there should not be any injection vunerability.

**Notes**

This answer is my best guess at how to do it, but better methods may exist.